# String replacement in bash - bad substitution error

Tags: linux, bash

I newbie in bash scripting but i don't uderstand why it's not work

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=foobarfoobar
echo ${foo//bar/baz}
```

bad substitution error on line 3

Comment: It works fine on my shell. What's your default shell?

Comment: If you're trying to do a substitution, replacing bar with baz, then this is correct. It works on my machine, printing foobazfoobaz, with bash 3.2.48.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release it works in command line but not in the script

Comment: @Aristarhys Can you please do `echo $0` and `uname -a` on the command line and add it to your question. Also, if you can paste the error message from the shell. Do `./script.sh` on the command line and show the output in your question

Comment: aristarhys@aristarhys-desktop ~/CADET $ sh test
sh test
test
Linux aristarhys-desktop 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
test: 5: Bad substitution

Comment: #!/bin/bash
foo=foobarfoobar
echo $0
uname -a
echo ${foo//bar/baz}

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That substitution works fine in Bash 4.2.8 (and looks fine according to the documentation).

My best guess would be that you're not actually using Bash - how are you invoking the script? If you're doing `sh script.sh` you may well be running it with Dash or something similar (and Dash does indeed give a substitution error on line 3). Try explicitly running it with Bash (`bash script.sh`).

If it turns out you are actually using Dash, there's some useful information on the differences and how to go back to using Bash (if you want to) here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.10(1)-release

Comment: If on the command line you did `sh scriptname` then `sh` is a link to `dash` in ubuntu. +1 to @Chris

Comment: Oof.  God bless the Debian maintainers, but this is subtle and confusing.  It would be nice if << sh >> calls generating errors somehow included a warning that Dash, not Bash, is in use.

Comment: My problem came from an executable bash script called from within a Makefile.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ foo=foobarfoobar
$ echo ${foo}/bar/baz
foobarfoobar/bar/baz
```

Just that you have the braces in the wrong place, but then I am no expert at BASH, so perhaps this isn't the effect you're going for..

Comment: ${foo//bar/baz}
must replace all bar to baz, so echo will be foobazfoobaz http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: OP is doing global substitution using `//`. I don't think he wants to append `bar/baz` to his variable. He is looking to replace occurrences of `bar` with `baz` so that his output looks like `foobazfoobaz`

Comment: yeah in every bash string manipulation article use such code but it does not work for me