# Bash - bad substitution

Tags: bash

I have a short bash script to get source code's dependency files.

```
#!/bin/sh
rule=$(cpp -P -w -undef -nostdinc -C -M file.cc)
rule=${rule##*:}
#echo $rule
echo ${rule//\\}
```

Unfortunately, it outputs `./findDep.sh: 5: ./findDep.sh: Bad substitution`.
But if I uncomment `echo $rule`, the script will execute without any problem:

```
lib.h macro.inc fundamental.h lib/fs.h lib/net.h \ lib/net/fetch.h
lib.h macro.inc fundamental.h lib/fs.h lib/net.h  lib/net/fetch.h
```

Any one know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's add. can you please add set -x?

Comment: Change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh -x`, or add a `set -x` (`-e` could be helpful too) on a line before the first command.

Comment: @ephemient: sorry It didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't *fix* anything; `-x` causes execution to be traced (printing all commands to stderr as they are run), and `-e` causes abort upon any failed command (that is, not used in a logical context), both of which are generally useful for pinpointing problems in shell scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replacement in bash - bad substitution error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960677/string-replacement-in-bash-bad-substitution-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem here with Bash 4.2.29.

However, did you know that `read` will join lines with `\` newline continuations by default?

```
read rule < <(cpp -P -w -undef -nostdinc -C -M file.cc)
echo "${rule##*:}"
```

Or, in a more `sh`-compatible way (I think),

```
cpp -P -w -undef -nostdinc -C -M file.cc | {
    read rule
    echo "${rule##*:}"
}
```

Comment: Seems that my system link /bin/sh to /bin/dash instead of /bin/bash

Answer (score 5):

You should change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works. but seems @ephemient's solution is more elegent.