# Jmeter --- generate separate .jtl result file for every run

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

How to generate a separate .jtl result file for each run. Following is my command which i am running using jenkins job (Performance trend plugin).

cd /apache-jmeter-2.13/bin
./jmeter.sh -n -t /jmxFiles/Jbpm6Rest3Jenkins1.jmx -l /jmxFiles/SIP.jtl  -JUSERS=${USER_COUNT} -JRampUp=${RAMP_UP} -JLoopCount=${LOOP_COUNT}

Currently SIP.jtl file is appending result in same file for every run.
How to generate a separate .jtl result file for each run (SIP1, SIP2, SIP3 etc) and should display in Jenkins performance trend.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
you just need to add time function just after or before your JTL file name
```

> Example:- jmeter -n -t Test_Plan.jmx -l
>   LOG_${__time(yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SS)}.jtl

[image]

Comment: Its working fine in windows. But in linux showing following error                     /jmxFiles/SIP_${__time(yy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SS)}.jtl: bad substitution

Comment: I am not sure about the linux machine but may be this [bad substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960677/string-replacement-in-bash-bad-substitution-error) post will help full for you.

Comment: /jmxFiles/SIP_$(date +'%d:%m:%Y%H:%M:%S:%3N').jtl this works for me