# Assigning the output of a bash string manipulation to a variable

Tags: bash, sed, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04, I have a bash script which I run as root. I want to remove all spaces from the user's input, and assign the trimmed string to a variable.

```
read -p "Enter username: " USERNAME
echo "$USERNAME" | sed s/' '/''/g
TRIM="$USERNAME" | sed s/' '/''/g
echo $TRIM
echo "Done"
```

Here's some sample input and output:

> Enter username: h j k l
>   hjkl
>
> Done

$TRIM is empty.
What change do I need to make to get $TRIM to contain the result?

Answer (score 5):

Use `$()` to capture the output of a command.

```
trim=$(echo "$USERNAME" | sed 's/ //g')
```

However, you don't need a command for this, you can use the `bash` [parameter expansion operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to do substitution.

```
trim=${username// /}
```

P.S. Don't use uppercase variable names, they're conventionally reserved for environment variables.

Comment: If I use the bash parameter expansion operator, I get `./trim.sh: 3: ./trim.sh: Bad substitution`

Comment: Then you're not really using `bash`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960677/string-replacement-in-bash-bad-substitution-error

Comment: @JamesNewton : You're probably missing the `echo`

Comment: @sjsam There's no `echo` in the command he got the error from.

Comment: @Barmar : The code in question has many problems as you might have noted. For instance, where are quotes to encapsulate the sed command? Might be a copy paste error though.

Comment: @sjsam He has the quotes inside: `s/' '/''/g` The second quotes aren't needed, though.

Comment: @Barmar : Oh I see, I overlooked those..

Comment: Understandable, since it's so unusual. At first I thought he was trying to replace explicit quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you should note with your script.

First of all, uppercase identifiers like `USERNAME` are usually reserved for environment variables. So you might well override a shell variable accidentally that causes undesired effects. Same is the case with `TRIM`.

Secondly, you should check the default shell in your Ubuntu distribution using the `SHELL` built-in. Do something like

```
echo $SHELL
```

If the output is `dash` or `bash`, you could use command substitution to achieve your objective.

```
trim=$(echo "$username" | sed 's/ //g')
```

Mind that the `sed` commands themselves should be put under the single quotes.

When you echo `trim`, use double quotes to prevent word splitting like

```
echo "$trim" # In your case though the double quotes doesn't make any difference
```

Comment: Actually the quotes make a lot of a difference.  If the user inputs an expression containing a shell wildcard character or irregular whitespace, the program without quotes will mess up the output.